# Android SDK info about XML Layout tag attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm studying the Android SKD Documentation and I was wondering where I can find information about the XML tags' attributes that are used when defining the layout of the interface of your application, like the *android:name*, *android:id*, *class:* attributes of the fragment tag etc.. I can not find them in the Reference documentation, which lists only the documentation of Java classes.. Is there any specific documentation about XML tags and attributes, organized like the Java Reference docs?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that: it is in there. The layout tags specific to a class are typically in a subclass *LayoutParams* for example [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). However since most classes we use are derived from some (great-great-grand-)parent class, we climb up the hierarchy to find until we find the tag we want. The simplest way is to find details the attribute your are interested in is to search for it.

If you ever find a master list, let me know. Until then I rely on IDEs like Eclipse with auto-complete features for a quick reference.

Comment: What about the attributes of the <fragment> tag? I'd like to know more about this tag and its attributes, but I can not find it in the Fragment Class? For example I want to understand if there is a difference between using the *android:name* and the *class:* attributes to specify the Fragment class to be instantiated, as I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-andoirdname-attributes)

Comment: I found the _android:name_ and _class_ attributes (in R.attr and java docs respectively) but they are defined in such a generic way that they won't help. (To paraphrase: _class_ is the name of the class to which the element refers to...) I'm sorry but they do not contain the answer to your question.