# Activity Layout: Fragment class: vs android:name attributes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml, xml-attribute

I've read the documentation about [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) in the Android Developer Guide and I've seen that sometimes they specify the class to instantiate with the Fragment tag attribute *android:name* and sometime they use the *class:* attribute:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/viewer"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Are *android:name* and *class:* interchangeable? If I use the autocompletion function in Eclipse, they both show the same documentation tip (i.e. the attribute provides the class name to be instantiated). Maybe you must use the second one when the class to be instantiated has a name which is different from the java file name, like *TitlesFragment* which is in the *FragmentLayout.java* file? Or can I use the syntax *package.fileDOTjava$Class* also with the *android:name* attribute?

I'd like to have some documentation for XML tags and attributes as for Android Java Classes  (I've asked about it in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10162870/925001)).

Answer (score 46):

As Activity.onCreateView source says:

```
String fname = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "class");
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.Fragment);
if (fname == null) {
    fname = a.getString(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Fragment_name);
}
```

That seemingly means that program looks "class" attribute first. And on fail looks "name" attribute.
So as far as it's true using "class" if more efficient.

Comment: I just checked out, the basic template provided by Android Studio 2.0 uses `name:xxx` attribute by default.

Comment: "The android:name attribute in the <fragment> specifies the Fragment class to instantiate in the layout." This is the definition I saw in developer website. Page: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 26):

> Are android:name and class: interchangeable?

Presumably, yes. I have only used `class`, and that seems to be what most of Google's examples use, but I do see where they use `android:name` in some samples. Unfortunately, there is no formal and complete documentation for `<fragment>`.

Comment: I really wish there was documentation.  Since `class` doesn't have a namespace, I'm curious whether that attribute wasn't just used while fragments were being developed but were left in because they can't break compatibility now.  For consistency's sake, `android:name` seems ever so slightly preferable and as user1550716 pointed out, they appear to be interchangeable.

Comment: @spaaarky21: Yeah, I've switched over to `android:name` everywhere.

Comment: additional credence for usage of name vs class: IntelliJ IDEA uses/autofills the name attribute in its latest layout editor (v13)

Comment: aapt r20 had a bug which only affected `class` and @xavier-ducrohet recommended `android:name`. https://plus.google.com/+XavierDucrohet/posts/7uRN3ba8zxt

Comment: Do we need a fully qualified class name? Or can we just `.ArticleReaderFragment`?

Comment: @Kenny: AFAIK, it has to be a fully-qualified class name, but I haven't tried a bare class name recently. I would be a bit surprised if the leading-dot notation worked.

Comment: @CommonsWare Eclipse keeps suggesting a fully qualified name... I'll just go with what works I guess. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all experts are here, I may be wrong but as per my knowledge **android:name** attribute of fragment is used to find fragment, when we use **getFragmentByTag()** method of fragmentManager class. 
also **android:class** attribute is used to find fragment class which we generally include for **static fragment**.

Hope this will help..
thanks

Comment: According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), they use the `android:tag` attribute for that, which makes sense: `android:tag can be used in <fragment> to provide a specific tag name for the fragment`