# Google Map API is not loading in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am try to develop a project on Google Map API in android. I am using Eclipse version of JUNO, SDK level-17.

The problem is, when the application is start loading, it is showing an unfortunate error. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="xxx...xxx"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am getting the error message like below:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
```

Do me another favor plz...
Why does google API library is not adding into my project?

[image: This is error]
Any help please...

Comment: shows us your code and manifest file

Comment: extend `FragmentActivity` and give it a try.

Comment: Cart did you try the below by extending `FragmentActivity`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class must extend `FragmentActivtiy`

Make sure you import

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Since you rmin sdk is 8 you should use SupportMapFrament.

You can also check this as a side note.

[Activity Layout: Fragment class: vs android:name attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes)

This is the later part of initializing GoogleMap object and using the same.

To initialize Google Map Object

You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap mMap = fm.getMap();
```

Import

```
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Edit:

You must Choose the Google API's instead of Android 4.2.2.

Also make sure you refer to the google library project properly. Looks like it's a broken link from the picture posted.

Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace (folder where your map project is). The library project can be found under the following path.

```
     <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project .
```

Import the library project into eclipse

Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the     workspace  import the library project. You can check if it is library project. Right click on the library project. Goto properties. Click Android on the left panel. You will see Is Library checked.

You need to refer the google-play services_lib library project in your android project.

Right click on your android project.  Goto properties. Choose Android on the left panel. Click on Add and browse the library project. Select the same. Click ok and apply.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ya, my workspace is outside of C drive. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 1):

```
<fragment
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Use `class` instead of `android:name`

Comment: The `android:name` attribute in the `<fragment>` **specifies** the `Fragment class` to instantiate in the layout. I don't think that's the problem here. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1):

In class file you are using `Fragment.Use SupportMapFragment`

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

GoogleMap gm;
gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```