# Error inflating Class Fragment in Recyclerview with Multiple Views

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a recyclerview with 2 layouts,
One is for my google map,
and Two is for the extra details for what i have to point in the map.

My code in my adapter is this.

```
public class AdapterTrending extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTrending.MyTrendingHolder> {
private int viewType = 0;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> reviewTrending = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterTrending(Context context, ArrayList<String> reviewTrending) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.reviewTrending = reviewTrending;
}

@Override
public MyTrendingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(viewType);
        if (listViewItemType == 0) {
            return new MyGoogleMap(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_googlemap_layout, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new MyTrendings(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_trending_layout, parent, false));
        }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyTrendingHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        viewType = 0;
    }
    if (position >= 1) {
        viewType = position;
    }
    return viewType;
}


class MyTrendings extends MyTrendingHolder {
    public MyTrendings(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class MyGoogleMap extends MyTrendingHolder {
    public MyGoogleMap(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class MyTrendingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public MyTrendingHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```

I have tabpager with three tabs.
First tab is this.
Second and third page have nothing.
When i swipe to third page and back to second page,
this error occur.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: com.toweelo, PID: 22695
                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                             at com.toweelo.adapter.AdapterTrending.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterTrending.java:31)
                                                             at com.toweelo.adapter.AdapterTrending.onCreateViewHolder(AdapterTrending.java:17)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5228)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4453)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:761)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5302)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2102)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1956)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1865)
                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16542)
                                                            at android.view.V
```

And for my XML which is the error directing me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/googleMap"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest, inflate the SupportMapFragment **programmatically** instead of adding the fragment in XML.

```
public class AdapterTrending extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTrending.MyTrendingHolder> {

private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private int viewType = 0;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> reviewTrending = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterTrending(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<String> reviewTrending) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    this.reviewTrending = reviewTrending;
}

@Override
public MyTrendingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int listViewItemType = getItemViewType(viewType);
        if (listViewItemType == 0) {
            return new MyGoogleMap(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_googlemap_layout, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new MyTrendings(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_trending_layout, parent, false));
        }
}

  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExperienceListHolder holder, int position) {
    // Setup other views here

    SupportMapFragment fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction
            .replace(R.id.map_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        viewType = 0;
    }
    if (position >= 1) {
        viewType = position;
    }
    return viewType;
}


class MyTrendings extends MyTrendingHolder {
    public MyTrendings(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class MyGoogleMap extends MyTrendingHolder {
    public MyGoogleMap(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class MyTrendingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public MyTrendingHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```

And the XML will now look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: okay i will try this.. but why the error like that occurs? so that i can prevent it next time

Comment: I hope you have added play services version and maps v2 API key to your AndroidManifest.xml
If not, please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768934/android-binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-fragment

Comment: yes. I have it in my manifest. I have another activity which has map and it working properly.

Comment: Ok. Finally got the answer.
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Apparently, nested fragments can only be used, when inflated dynamically. :)

Comment: not yet, still having with this part getChildFragmentManager and with this fragment.getMapAsync(this);.. I am using a recyclerview adapter so getChildFragmentManager is not there

Comment: Oh... I assumed that the RecyclerView is contained in a fragment.
In that case, you can simply use
`getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: You might have to pass the FragmentManager to the Adapter (via the constructor)

Comment: saw some code in stack and i tried passing parentFragment and i received this error. android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
            options.liteMode(true);
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragment.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction
                    .replace(R.id.mapHolder, mFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(new MapReadyCallback());

Comment: Please check updated answer.
All you need to do now is to call the Adapter in the following way:
`new AdapterTrending(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), reviewTrending)`