# Adding Fragment to Activity in XML: What is the class attribute and why doesn't it have a namespace

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml, android-listfragment

In the following snippet,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**what is the `class` attribute, if it is the our Fragment class, then why is `FragmentLayout$` appended to its name, and why is it without `android` or any namespace?**

I can totally see that it is the name of the Fragment class, because `TitlesFragment` is the Fragment class in the [example I took this code from](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example), and `com.example.android.apis.app` tells me that we have to give this attribute a fully qualified name of the class, but what is `FragmentLayout$` part appended to the name of the class, that is `TitlesFragment`?

I have taken this code from the example in [this developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), but there is no explanation of the class attribute. I could not find anything relevant [here in the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) either. Pardon me if it is something too fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does refer to the Fragment class. `FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment` means that `TitlesFragment` is a public, static nested class in the `FragmentLayout` class. If you inspect [that class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.java), you'll see that it's a `ListFragment` subclass.

```
public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
```

The only reference to that notation I've ever seen in the developer pages is on the [Custom Components page.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying) (It's under sub-heading **4. Use the Custom Component**.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just inspected a bit and learned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name) that $ is used "internally" by the compiler to decorate certain variable names, e.g. when an `InnerClass` class inside an `OuterClass` class is compiled, the `.class` formed will be named `OuterClass$InnerClass.class` by the compiler. This confuses me, is this named by the compiler, or do we just simply use a `$` sign to refer to the `.class` version of an innerclass, which we normally refer with the dot notation: OuterClass.InnerClass?

Comment: Secondly, isn't the `android:name` attribute already there to refer to the fragment class?

Comment: Thank you for the link, it pretty much gives an idea to quite an extent.

Comment: That post wouldn't be relevant here, since it pertains to the Java language. We're taking about Android layout xml; the Java compiler never touches that directly. As for the `android:name` attribute, as far as I know, it is almost the same thing, in that if `class` isn't found, `name` is then used. However, I believe that you must use `class` in this particular instance; i.e., with that notation for a static inner class.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes) discusses `class` vs `name`.

Comment: I was incorrect. I just ran a test, and you can use the `android:name` attribute with the `$` notation. So it would seem that `class` and `android:name` are completely interchangeable. As a comment in the link I posted suggests, `class` just might be a hold-over from the early days of Fragment development.