# Android : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

XML layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context="com.gaurav.googlemap.HomeMap" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
</fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file

```
package com.beproject.ourway;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class HomeMap extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_map);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

As I searched this question before also, I have done following things to solve

1.Imported following classes

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;  
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

2.Extended `FragmentActivity` class

Still I am getting this error in logcat

```
Error inflating class fragment
```

Is there any other way to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have used 'support fragment' you need to replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment`. Doing this should fix it.

Use:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

instead of :

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

so your xml must be like:

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain difference between class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" and android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes

Comment: I don't understand what you're meant to do in the case where your fragment class is not known in advance?  For instance, if you've got a layout that reserves space for a `Fragment`, but the particular fragment that you display in that space varies depending upon the current application state.  How is it meant to be set up then?