# What does android:name attribute do?

Tags: java, android

I want to know what does `android:name` attribute do?
What's the different between class attribute and it?
I use it for fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both do the same thing: identify the Java class that is the implementation of the fragment. AFAIK, `android:name` is the preferred attribute to use.

Comment: android:class is preferable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950563/3496570

Answer (score 1):

The android:name attribute specifies the Fragment class to instantiate in the layout.