# Map fragment activity crash, android?

Tags: android, fragment, supportmapfragment

I have map fragment activity

This is the layout file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The activity code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Exception is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vfirst.godfather/com.vfirst.godfather.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2154)
at com.vfirst.godfather.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at maps.G.a.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.V.N.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.e.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.D.p.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ad.M.a(Unknown Source)
at ul.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5371)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2154) 
at com.vfirst.godfather.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:20)
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: Please add your AndroidManifest.xml and entire layout file, not just the fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this lines:

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

for this lines of code:

```
MapFragment map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    map.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess along with W.Kurek's answer, this might be needed :

You can either change your SupportMapFragment to MapFragment as suggested by W.Kurek **OR** make changes to your XML layout like shown below and continue to use the same Java code in your activity.

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Notice that I have used `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead of the `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

The difference between the two can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes)