# SupportMapFragment cannot be added to FrameLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

> I have added mapFragment to FrameLayout in onCreate of an Activity like

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container,//where frame_container is a FrameLayout
                 new MapyFragment(),
                 MapyFragment.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
```

and frame_container is a `FrameLayout`

**MapyFragment.class**

```
public class MapyFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapy, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();/// getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();/// getChildFragmentManager();
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
        if (supportMapFragment == null) {
            supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, supportMapFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (supportMapFragment != null) {
            supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    map = googleMap;
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing with getChildFragmentManager and getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().

Google map doesn't show. No crash, What am i doing wrong. please clarify and

And why do we have to use fragmentManger to get our map_container. See

```
fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
```

**fragment_mapy.xml**

```
<fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        map:uiZoomControls="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

initialize your `supportMapFragment` in `onCreateview`.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);
    smp = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    smp.getMapAsync(this);
    retrun rootView;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
}
```

in layout xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Also read about [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) here

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to my own problem**

First of all there is no difference **b/w** `android:name` & `android:class` both work fine. [**See this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10163467/3496570)

**getChildFragmentManager()** is the culprit.

> Latest working class

```
public class MapyFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapy,container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();/// getChildFragmentManager();
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
        if (supportMapFragment == null) {
            supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, supportMapFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }
}
```