# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13..While using MapFragment

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to include maps in my android app so I followed the official docs and ended up with these files

fragment_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the map fragment"/>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context="com.example.nirmal.attendancetracker"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

MapsFragment.java:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map,container,false);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return subView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }
}
```

As you may have seen from my code. I am trying to show the map in a fragment which in turn is shown as a part of a `ViewPager`. I did everything as per the documentatio but the app is crashing with the following error when I run it

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                          Process: com.example.nirmal.attendancetracker, PID: 31903
                                                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                          at com.example.nirmal.attendancetracker.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:27)
```

I have seen these errors before. They are usually caused by wrong XML statements. Since I am new to this maps thing I am unable to find any errors in that.

Is XML file the issue? or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Add the remainder of the logcat, please. `InflateException` shouldn't be the only error

Comment: Also, you should really fix `MapFragment extends Fragment` to extend `SupportMapFragment`.... There is no reason to put a Fragment in a Fragment here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `SupportMapFragment` from `Fragment` its best prectice ot Use `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` instead of `SupportMapFragment`

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

**Your MapFragment class as below:**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) subView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.1, -37.9), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return subView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I have some clarifications in this..When I open the maps by default it is in the zoomed out state. What changes should I make so that it is zoomed in on the current location of the user?

Comment: I have updated my answer. try this: CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.1, -37.9), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate); // change latlong as per your position

Comment: Thanks. Will try this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! Try adding android:name="com.testing.shivam.MainActivity" to "fragment" in the layout! It solved the issue for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="com.testing.shivam.MainActivity"/>
```

If this doesn't work for you then check whether you have properly added meta tag for google_play_services_version in your manifest file under application tag,

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: `android:name` conflicts with `class`. And you should use a Fragment, not an Activity there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes

Comment: Dude I am posting my answer, Didn't reusing his code

Comment: I'm just saying that `android:name="com.testing.shivam.MainActivity"` is probably going to crash the app...

Comment: It was perfectly working for me so I thought this information will be helpful for somebody

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. I'm simply pointing out that it doesn't quite make sense to put an `Activity` within a `<fragment>` tag (Unless your MainActivity is actually a Fragment...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have confused [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) and have attempted to place a Fragment within a Fragment.

I also see you are not inflating your `MapFragment` class... So, the error seems to exist elsewhere.

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Quoting the documentation...

> By default, the XML file that defines the app's layout is at
>   `res/layout/activity_maps.xml`. It contains the following code:
>
> ```
> <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:id="@+id/map"
>     tools:context=".MapsActivity"
>     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
> ```
>
> #### The maps activity Java file
>
> By default, the Java file that defines the maps activity is named
>   `MapsActivity.java`. It should contain the following code after your
>   package name:
>
> ```
> public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
>
>     private GoogleMap mMap;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
>         SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
>                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
>         mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
>         mMap = googleMap;
> ```

So, all that code shown in your question should really be in an Activity, not a Fragment, and then replace

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)
```

With simply

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)
```

---

If you really want to extend the `SupportMapFragment` class, start with this

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

And load that in the XML

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME.MapFragment" />   <!--- See here --->
```