# Error inflating class fragment Caused by: "Fragment did not create a view."

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My Android app is presenting this error when users re-open the app. The first time the app opens normally. It just happen in some devices (sometimes) and I`m not able to solve it. There are some questions about it here in Stackoverflow, but none of them were answered correctly for me.

Here is the full error from Firebase crash:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[REDACTED_DOMAIN_NAME]/com.app.Activities.Activities.PrincipalActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2434)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:153)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1347)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5451)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)


Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:393)
android.app.Activity.setContentView (Activity.java:2215)
comwe.app.Activities.Activities.PrincipalActivity.onCreate (PrincipalActivity.java:60)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6323)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:153)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1347)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5451)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:782)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:393)
android.app.Activity.setContentView (Activity.java:2215)
com.app.Activities.Activities.PrincipalActivity.onCreate (PrincipalActivity.java:60)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6323)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:153)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1347)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5451)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)


Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.app.Activities.Activities.EmptyFragment did not create a view.
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView (FragmentManager.java:3706)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView (FragmentController.java:111)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:338)
android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView (BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:67)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:754)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:374)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView (PhoneWindow.java:393)
android.app.Activity.setContentView (Activity.java:2215)
com.app.Activities.Activities.PrincipalActivity.onCreate (PrincipalActivity.java:60)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6323)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:153)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1347)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5451)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Activity:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

             mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_place, anotherFragment).commit();
```

Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_principal2"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.Activities.Activities.PrincipalActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        class = "com.app.Activities.Activities.EmptyFragment"
        />
```

Fragment XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.Activities.Activities.EmptyFragment">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment class:

```
public class EmptyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_empty, container, false);



        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: show your EmptyFragment class.

Comment: Did you forget to implement `onCreateView` in the Fragment class?

Comment: @NoumanCh, I added.

Comment: @cricket_007  No, onCreateView is there.

Comment: Can you use a FrameLayout rather than a `<fragment>` if all you want is an "empty" section of a layout?

Comment: @cricket_007 start the app with a empty fragment because if I start with the main fragment it does not load. (I'm using roughike/BottomBar) So I add the main after start. This error is happening mostly on Samsung's.

Comment: Again, did you try a FrameLayout? There's no reason to create a Fragment just to have it be empty.

Comment: @cricket_007. Yes, I did. I also tried to load another fragment instead of the "EmptyFragment" but it's still not working.

Comment: You shouldn't get any errors about loading any Fragment class if you just use a FrameLayout. I bet you have some   different error or changed the wrong XML

Answer (score 0):

try to change your fragment.

from:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        class = "com.app.Activities.Activities.EmptyFragment"
        />
```

to:

```
<fragment
        android:name="com.app.Activities.Activities.EmptyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        />
```

and remove this line of code to your`PrincipalActivity`.

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_place, anotherFragment).commit();
```

Hope this help!

Comment: It was my first code. I changed because was happening the same problem and in other questions was saying to do it.

Comment: @RodrigoTaborda I tried this with your code, but mine is working. can you show us where the `EmptyFragment` located?

Comment: @RodrigoTaborda I think you need to double check your `EmptyFragment` so you can modify the value of `android:name` of your `fragment`

Comment: Those are the same behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162983/activity-layout-fragment-class-vs-androidname-attributes

Comment: @Jerrol. Mine is working fine too. I'm getting this error via Firebase. There are many instances, but I cannot fix. I already tried "name" and "class", but as cricket_007 said, they have the same behavior.

Comment: @RodrigoTaborda, Ohh, I think you need to provide more or update your codes in question more specifically. because the code shown is working fine (like what I did I copied your code and it's working).

Comment: **It just happen in some devices (sometimes) and I'm not able to solve it.** as your statement. did you try to change your `FragmentActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`?